# How can I get records which created by specific license id in populated object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a two models which named `User` and `Question`.

`User` model have `license` property and `Question` model have `created_by` property.

`Question`'s `created_by` property is reference to `User` model.

How can I get questions which `created_by` specific user by `license` id?

I try this:

```
QuestionResource
.find({'created_by.license':req.query.license})
.exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) res.json(err)
    else res.json(result)
})
```

But doesn't seem working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `match` option of the **[`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)** method as follows:

```
QuestionResource
    .find()
    .populate({
        path: 'created_by',
        match: { 'license': req.query.license }
    })
    .exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) res.json(err)
        var docs = result.filter(function(doc){
            return doc.created_by.length;
        });
        res.json(docs)
    })
```

Comment: It's returned matched row but in the same time returned other rows without their created_by property.

Comment: You can add another filter step after the query returns